# upload video on vine programatically using objective c

Tags: video, file-upload, xcode5, vine

i am using unofficial api (https://github.com/VineAPI/VineAPI/ ) for uploading video on vine but not succeed till now.
 if anyone uploaded vine please let me know.

thanx in advance

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I am trying the same thing and after success from upload, I never see a new post created.

Comment: if upload success and then you can not find the video uploaded this means they are deleted your video because of video encoding.
Check your video format that should be MPEG4

Comment: Thanks @Gufran for replying. For testing purposes I am uploading an mp4 video created by vine official app so the encoding is fine. However, I am unaware of how I need to get the video URL, I am using the video URL returned by the PUT request response header. However, the video URL I get from that does not contain any "?versionId=xxxxxxxxx" version ID. How do I get that? If I do put a dummy version ID there, the post shows up but does not play.

Comment: Hello @Gufran and Matt Have you successfully shared video on Vine. and the post is shown to all? I need help. I go through whole document and i'm always facing same error while uploading - "You must be logged in to perform this action."

Answer (score 0):

Yes logged in first then Check your video format that should be MPEG4(AVFileTypeMPEG4) and also check that headers like if you are having request object named "postRequest" then

```
[postRequest setValue:@"media.vineapp.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[postRequest setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:databody];
```

databody is the data of video.